# Get value not too close to last value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that will echo a new value between 1 and 6, but it can't be within + or - 1 of the last time the function was run. (i.e. If the last time it ran it got 4, I need a new value between 1 and 6 that's not 3, 4, or 5.)

As a php noob here's what I have so far:

```
    $prev_val = 8;
    function wordsize () {
        global $prev_val;
        $size_array = range(1,6);
        do {
            $new_val = $size_array[array_rand($size_array)];
        } while($new_val>$prev_val-1 && $new_val<$prev_val+1);
        echo "$new_val";
        $prev_val = $new_val;
    }
```

Comment: Don't you want `$new_val >= $prev_val - 1 && $new_val <= $prev_val + 1`?

Comment: Also, you may want to use `>=` & `<=`.

Comment: Another option is this:  `$size_array = array_diff(range(1,6), range($prev_val - 1, $prev_val + 1))`, which removes the need for a `while` altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$size_array = array_diff(range(1,6), range($prev_val - 1, $prev_val + 1));
```

Which removes the need for a `while` entirely.

Answer (score 4):

You almost got it, you need to use >= and <= in your while loop:

```
while($new_val>=$prev_val-1 && $new_val<=$prev_val+1);
```

However, it might be better to get rid of the while loop entirely. See @wrikken's answer.

Comment: I'd add a couple of parentheses just to make sure you don't mess with precedence and stuff. And it helps improve readability, too!

Comment: @AmalMurali While it might indeed help readability, && has quite low order-of-operation, shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Right; But it might be confusing to someone else reading your code :)